# Center an imageview in half of parentview without using LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

The way my layout is designed at the moment is that I have a `LinearLayout` having a `width="match_parent"`. This view has two ImageViews as its children, which take up half of the LinearLayouts width using `weight="1"`

The problem is that this way, onClicks are registered on transparent portions of the card, because the View is stretched.

Edit: I should have mentioned, that these circles are only supposed to represent image files and not circle-shapes filled with a solid color.

My current code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The red portion indicates touch areas

[image: x]

what I want is something like the following while keeping the ratios: [image: this]

I know that I could simply try to nest each ImageView in a RelativeLayout like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

but nesting like this is pretty horrible form

Comment: use percentage relative layout no nesting required [link here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Comment: @Bali that works like a charm, thanks! If you submit your comment as an answer, I will mark it as such!

Comment: i have added my answer as comment please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use percentage relative layout no nesting required [link here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Comment: worked like a charm, I ended up using the PercentageRelativeLayout with `width="match_parent"` and assigned `marginLeftPercentage` and `marginRightPercentage` as `17%`

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But this will cause overlapping sometime if the aspect ratio of screen is less.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the color of the pixel that was touched and act accordingly :

```
 final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

        int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
        int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
        int greenValue = Color.green(pixel); 
        if(redValue != 255 && blueValue != 255 && greenValue != 255) {
            //Not the background, so handle the click
        }
        return false;
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new component: `res/drawable/my_circle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/your_color" />
</shape>
```

And then set as source in your `ImageView`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/my_circle" />

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/my_circle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it is not what op wants